# how to identify if a number is of float or double type in java

Tags: java

How 19.5 is a double value. Why we need to append `F` to it to make it `float`? Just want to know how we identify a number whether it is `float` or `double`.

Comment: You need to put the `F` if you're assigning it to a `float` variable or passing it as a `float` parameter.

Comment: please explain a bit more

Comment: The decimal on its own is the syntax for a double. `f` at the end denotes that its a `float`. Thats just how the language was designed

Comment: The answer is in the question. If a floating point number literal ends with F of f, it's a float. Otherwise, it's a double. What else do you want to know?

Comment: @flakes . you mean if we have 2 digits before period then it's a double value else float right??

Comment: @JBNizet please explain this statement "float value= 19.2;" why do i need to append F with it as i have already mentioned float in it

Comment: The syntax is `[0-9]*\.[0-9]+` or  `[0-9]+\.[0-9]*` for double and append an `f` for a float. e.g. `123. , .123 , 123.123` or floats `123.f , .123f , 123.123f`

Comment: i agree with the comment from @flakes

Comment: `float value = 19.2` needs the `F` because it is being assigned to a `float` variable, as I already told you.

Comment: float value= 19.2; tries to assign a double (19.2) to a variable of type float (value). A double is not a float, so the compiler teels you that this is invalid. Assigning a float value to a variable of type float, on the other hand, is valid. And 19.2F is a float, since it ends with F.

Comment: @akhilsk Your link is totally irrelevant. Please don't add to the confusion.

Comment: @EJP what is the difference i mean i want to know how you identify that i need to append 'F' with it

Comment: @Rahul For the third time, *because it is being assigned to a `float` variable*. If you don't understand that, please say so, but don't just ignore it and keep asking the same question when it's already been answered.

Comment: @akhilsk The question is about when to append the `F` to a floating-point literal, and there is nothing in your link that addresses that even tangentially.

Comment: @akhilsk What about the middle part? 'Why we need to append F to it to make it `float`?' I can only suggest you read it again, and the question he has now asked three or four times in comments. You don't appear to have got beyond the title as far as I can see.

Comment: @EJP i think i am not getting you....this concept is totally unclear to me....let me tell you what i understand from upper comment is if we write any value like 12.3,2.2,121.21,12.12 etc these are double values and if we assign it float type then we need to append F with it correct??

Comment: That's exactly what I have already stated, three times.

Comment: @Rahul People will be a lot happier to help you if they don't have to say the same thing three times only to have it all repeated back to them for a fourth confirmation. If you were able to replay it back and understand the confirmation there's no reason why you couldn't have got it the first time. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`19.5` is a floating-point literal in java. Quote from [Java Language Specification #3.10.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2):

> A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter F or f; otherwise, its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d.

---

Now when we know that `19.5` is of type double, let's look at your example in the comments:

```
float value = 19.5;
```

Conversion from `double` to `float` in java is a [narrowing primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3). This type of conversion should be explicit. That's why you need to use floating-point literal of type `float` to get rid of the conversion

```
float value = 19.5f;
```

or to make this conversion explicit

```
float value = (float) 19.5;
```

Answer (score 1):

For handling downcasts, or narrowing conversions. Whenever you downcast a long to an int, or a double to a float, the possibility for data loss exists. So, the compiler will force you to indicate that you really want to perform the narrowing conversion, by signaling a compile error for something like this:

`float f = 19.5;`

Because 19.5 represents a double, you have to explicitly cast it to a float (basically signing off on the narrowing conversion). Otherwise, you could indicate that the number is really a float, by using the correct suffix;

`float f = 19.5f;`

by default 19.5 is double literal, So to tell compiler to treat it as float explicitly -> it uses f or F

Comment: i am trying to make my answer more usefull @EJP

Comment: i will be trying  @EJP

Comment: no, i don't think so,i have edited my answer again @EJP